# Ruby on Rails: Rake: rake stats didn't add my field to the correct value?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

Before my rake stats modification

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Name                 | Lines |   LOC | Classes | Methods | M/C | LOC/M |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Controllers          |  5037 |  3936 |      31 |     292 |   9 |    11 |
| Helpers              |   150 |   128 |       0 |      17 |   0 |     5 |
| Models               |  1523 |  1166 |      42 |     123 |   2 |     7 |
| Libraries            |   633 |   415 |       4 |      65 |  16 |     4 |
| Functional tests     |   289 |   228 |      13 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Unit tests           |   560 |   389 |      30 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Model specs          |  1085 |   904 |       0 |       3 |   0 |   299 |
| View specs           |    88 |    75 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Controller specs     |   468 |   388 |       0 |       2 |   0 |   192 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Total                |  9833 |  7629 |     120 |     502 |   4 |    13 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
  Code LOC: 5645     Test LOC: 1984     Code to Test Ratio: 1:0.4
```

now, when I add:

```
#Factories
::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Factories\ specs test/factories) if File.exist?('test/factories')
::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Factory specs" if File.exist?('test/factories')
```

around line 120, it should increase test LOC, right?

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Controllers          |  5037 |  3936 |      31 |     292 |   9 |    11 |
| Helpers              |   150 |   128 |       0 |      17 |   0 |     5 |
| Models               |  1523 |  1166 |      42 |     123 |   2 |     7 |
| Libraries            |   633 |   415 |       4 |      65 |  16 |     4 |
| Functional tests     |   289 |   228 |      13 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Unit tests           |   560 |   389 |      30 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Model specs          |  1085 |   904 |       0 |       3 |   0 |   299 |
| View specs           |    88 |    75 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
| Controller specs     |   468 |   388 |       0 |       2 |   0 |   192 |
| Factories specs      |   144 |   119 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Total                |  9977 |  7748 |     120 |     502 |   4 |    13 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
  Code LOC: 5764     Test LOC: 1984     Code to Test Ratio: 1:0.3
```

Instead of adding tho 144 lines from factories to test LOC, it adds them to code LOC =\ 
How do I get the line count to be in Test LOC?

Comment: If I were you, I'd spend more time improving my code:test ratio, rather than trying to game a 'better' result.

Comment: lol. That's what I'm doing. but metrics are still important. I was just taking a break from test writing while I wait on an answer to another question that was preventing my from running any ruby files =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding something called "Factories specs" (plural) to the `STATS_DIRECTORIES` array, but you call it "Factory specs" (singular) when you add it to `TEST_TYPES` array -- so when `rake:stat` hits your `test/factories` folder, it looks for "Factories specs" in `TEST_TYPES`, doesn't find it, and assumes it's code, not tests. You need to call it the same thing in both places:

```
::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Factory\ specs test/factories) if File.exist?('test/factories')
::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Factory specs" if File.exist?('test/factories')
```